# BINARY TO ASCII conversion using 'xxd'

Tags: binary, ascii

I know how to convert hex dump to ASCII.

`echo 54 58 72 56 etc | xxd -r -p` -> will produce ASCII output

But I'm struggling with converting following binary code to ASCII.

01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01111001 01101111 01110101 00100000 01100001 00100000 01101100 01101001 01110100 01110100 01101100 01100101 00100000 01110011 01101000 01101111 01110010 01110100 00100000 01100110 01101111 01110010 00100000 01100001 00100000 01110011 01110100 01101111 01110010 01101101 00100000 01110100 01110010 01101111 01101111 01110000 01100101 01110010 00111111 00001101 00001010

I need to do this using 'xxd' or similar as short as the possible command.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to stick with `xxd`, then you need to first convert each binary number to decimal. If you're using `bash`, and `x` contains your binary string, then:

```
for a in $x; do printf "%x" $((2#$a)); done | xxd -r -p
```

`$((2#$a))` is binary to decimal conversion in bash, and the `printf` will convert this to hex. Then just pipe it to `xxd` - and get what you got before.

> Aren't you a little short for a storm trooper?

If the string is contained in a file, read line by line and then word by word. Another option is using only `printf`, but then you need octal numbers, so using `printf` twice:

```
for a in $x; do printf \\$(printf "%o" $((2#$a))); done
```

Actually that last one can be done with `hex` as well, just use instead of `\\` `\\x` and `%o` reverts back to `%x`.

Answer (score 1):

A one liner to fix this is:

```
data=$(cat file.in); echo $(printf '%x\n' "$((2#$data))") | xxd -r -p > file.out
```

The problem is printf seems to have a character limit, which can be fixed by tokenizing the data into blocks your rig can handle eg. into 8 bytes each (on my Ubuntu 16.04.7)

One workaround is to loop a character (byte sequence) at a time or lines **from the file**:

```
data=$(cat file.in); for byte in $data; do echo $(printf '%x\n' "$((2#$byte))"); done | xxd -r -p
```

NO need to convert to octals or read line by line before separating into words.

A **dictionary/database/array** could be another but slower solution (if you have enough memory or don't want to store data in a file):

```
D2B=(01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01111001 01101111 01110101 00100000 01100001 00100000 01101100 01101001 01110100 01110100 01101100 01100101 00100000 01110011 01101000 01101111 01110010 01110100 00100000 01100110 01101111 01110010 00100000 01100001 00100000 01110011 01110100 01101111 01110010 01101101 00100000 01110100 01110010 01101111 01101111 01110000 01100101 01110010 00111111 00001101 00001010); 
count=${#D2B[@]}; 
run='D2C=('${D2B[@]}'); for word in {0..'$count'}; do echo -n $(printf '%x' "$((2#${D2C[$word]}))"); done;';
echo "$run" | bash | xxd -r -p
```

or a **string solution** passed to an array for faster response:

```
dat="01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01111001 01101111 01110101 00100000 01100001 00100000 01101100 01101001 01110100 01110100 01101100 01100101 00100000 01110011 01101000 01101111 01110010 01110100 00100000 01100110 01101111 01110010 00100000 01100001 00100000 01110011 01110100 01101111 01110010 01101101 00100000 01110100 01110010 01101111 01101111 01110000 01100101 01110010 00111111 00001101 00001010"; 
count=$(echo $dat ^| wc -w); 
run='D2C=('$dat'); for word in {0..'$count'}; do echo -n $(printf '%x' "$((2#${D2C[$word]}))"); done;'; 
echo "$run" | bash | xxd -r -p
```

or **string only** solution (no arrays):

```
dat="01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01111001 01101111 01110101 00100000 01100001 00100000 01101100 01101001 01110100 01110100 01101100 01100101 00100000 01110011 01101000 01101111 01110010 01110100 00100000 01100110 01101111 01110010 00100000 01100001 00100000 01110011 01110100 01101111 01110010 01101101 00100000 01110100 01110010 01101111 01101111 01110000 01100101 01110010 00111111 00001101 00001010"; 
count=$(echo $dat ^| wc -w); 
run='D2C="'$dat'"; for word in {0..'$count'}; do byte=${D2C:$((word+8*word)):8}; echo -n $(printf '%x' "$((2#$byte))"); done;'; 
echo "$run" | bash | xxd -r -p
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.7